# Issue with Git Lab My changes are not reflected even my tag is merged

Tags: gitlab

What happen with me like I created one branch say feature1 from develop. Now After that I raise an MR for Feature1 branch . Now we merge this branch successfully in develop  and tag genrated is 4.15.0.After that  some other people create branch and merge in develop and some other tags are created like 4.16.0 ans so on.
So the issue is when I looking into develop branch i did not see my feature1 branch changes.but when I took pull of my particular tag 4.15.0 my changes are there but not in develop branch even my changes are merge sucessfully.

I am expecting that I want my feature1 branch. Into develop.